# Converting an array to object

Tags: c#

I have 2 types of string: Mer and Spl

```
// Example
string testMer = "321|READY|MER";
string testSpl = "321|READY|SPL";
```

Then I will split them:

```
var splitMer = testMer.Split('|');
var splitSpl = testSpl.Split('|');
```

I have an object to save them

```
public class TestObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Question: How to convert the Array into the TestObject?

Comment: `new TestObject { id = Int.Parse(splitMer[0]), status = splitMer[1], type = splitMer[2] }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a Constructor to your Class that takes a String as a Parameter.  Something like this.

```
public class TestObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public TestObject(string value)
    {
        var valueSplit = value.Split('|');
        id = int.Parse(valueSplit[0]);
        status = valueSplit[1];
        type = valueSplit[2];

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TestObject tst1 = new TestObject(testMer);
TestObject tst2 = new TestObject(testSpl);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var converted = new TestObject 
               {
                  id = int.Parse(splitMer[0]),
                  status = splitMer[1],
                  type = splitMer[2]
               };
```

You will need to add some error checking.

Answer (score 4):

```
var values = new List<string> { "321|READY|MER", "321|READY|SPL" };

var result = values.Select(x =>
        {
            var parts = x.Split(new [] {'|' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new TestObject
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
                status = parts[1],
                type = parts[2]
            };
        }).ToArray();
```

You just need to use [`object initializers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and set your properties.By the way instead of storing each value into seperate variables, use a `List`.Then you can get your result with `LINQ` easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
var splitMer = testMer.Split('|');

var testObj = new TestObject();

testObj.Id = Int32.Parse(splitMer[0]);
testObj.Status = splitMer[1];
testObj.type = splitMer[2];
```

Comment: object initializers make job simpler :)

Comment: Also you can create an array of testObj as `var testObj[size]= new TestObject();` for storing multiple objects.